# No solution for Thunderbird date format

Tags: linux, thunderbird, date-time, date

I run Linux Mint 19.2 and Thunderbird 60.8.0 (July 2019). I am trying to change the UI to display the dates in a [reasonable date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/) called ISO 8601, and for that I tried setting `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` as suggested in several places. In fact, [this SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/1357797) points to a settings panel that apparently signals that I did this correctly:

[image: Date and Time Formatting setting]

However, the UI still displays the dates in an *unreasonable* date format:

[image: Date column]

Some other places mention the "Super Date Format" Thunderbird addon, but it does not work with recent versions of Thunderbird.

By looking at the output of `locale -k LC_TIME`, it seems that Thunderbird is completely ignoring it:

```
juanlu@voyager:~$ date +%x
2019-09-10
juanlu@voyager:~$ locale -k LC_TIME
abday="Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat"
day="Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday"
abmon="Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec"
mon="January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December"
am_pm=";"
d_t_fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%T %Z"
d_fmt="%Y-%m-%d"
t_fmt="%T"
t_fmt_ampm=""
era=
era_year=""
era_d_fmt=""
alt_digits=
era_d_t_fmt=""
era_t_fmt=""
time-era-num-entries=0
time-era-entries="S"
week-ndays=7
week-1stday=19971130
week-1stweek=4
first_weekday=2
first_workday=2
cal_direction=1
timezone=""
date_fmt="%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
time-codeset="UTF-8"
alt_mon="January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December"
ab_alt_mon="Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec"
juanlu@voyager:~$ thunderbird  # Nothing strange here
[calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's builtin libical backend

(thunderbird:3166): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:39:42.416: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:34: Expected ')' in color definition

(thunderbird:3166): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:39:42.416: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:78: Expected ')' in color definition
1568108384098   addons.xpi  WARN    Can't get modified time of /usr/lib/thunderbird/features/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net
*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe your thunderbird profile configuration messed up, try with new profile.

Comment: @BladeMight I tried a new profile, no luck.

Comment: Try asking on their support forum at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=39 .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Edit: There is now [official documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird#w_create-date-and-time-format-override-preferences-using-thunderbirds-config-editor) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230212020811/https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird#w_create-date-and-time-format-override-preferences-using-thunderbirds-config-editor)) on this. Thanks to @zx485 for pointing this out*

To add to the answer explaining how Thunderbird uses the CLDR, there recently has been some change. Thunderbird¹ now natively offers a set of preferences with which the date formatting patterns can be overridden:

- `intl.date_time.pattern_override.time_`(`short` | `medium` | `long` | `full`)
- `intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_`(`short` | `medium` | `long` | `full`)

To use these new preferences

1. Open the Thunderbird Preferences 

   [image: Screenshot of hamburger menu, preferences item]
2. Scroll down all the way and click the "Config Editor..." button. 

   [image: Screenshot of preferences page, bottom, config editor button]
3. Here you can enter one of the above preference names (e.g. `intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_full`) into the search bar. You can then either modify the value of the preference, if it already exists, or add the desired value as a preference by selecting "String", using the "+" button. 

   [image: Screenshot of config editor, adding new String preference]
4. Enter the desired pattern (e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z (EEEE)`) and and confirm with the checkmark button. 

   [image: Screenshot of config editor, entering value for and saving new String preference]

Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all preferences you wish to change. You might have to restart Thunderbird afterwards.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907#c182 (or [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20210322111805/https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907)) for some more details and examples of date patterns.

Comment: Coming back to this after many years, and I confirm this solution works!

Comment: As of version 102.6.0 these options have to be added manually. The disadvantage of this is that you cannot see the current(default) values.

Comment: @zx485 As far as I'm aware you have always had to add them manually. They are "hidden" override options that make firefox deviate from what your locale dictates (as defined by the CLDR). This is probably also the reason for why there isn't an visible-by-default option with a default value, since that is system config dependent.

Comment: Yes, this is right. Have a look at the [Mozilla article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird) describing this.

Comment: Ah, good to know that they have docs for that now. I'll edit my answer (crediting you) :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question “Why doesn’t Thunderbird’s output match my locale?”, the answer is that Thunderbird apparently uses a separate library ([CLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)) to format dates and times instead of the built-in locale data provided by your Linux distribution.

There is a [bug report on Thunderbird’s bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1509096) by someone who is trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use another locale than `en_DK.UTF-8`. Just install the locale for `sv_SE.UTF-8`. On Debian I do it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and select that Swedish locale. Then start thunderbird as usual:

```
~$ LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8 thunderbird
```

This works with some older thunderbird versions but definitely with version 78.3.1 I'm just using.

Comment: Thank you, this works in thunderbird 78.13.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to *why this doesn't work* is still a mistery.

However, I found a successful workaround in another extension: [Enhanced Date Formatter](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/enhanced-date-formatter/)

[image: Proper datetime format]

❤️

<sup>I asked this [on the Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=301487) without noticing that [someone else had asked exactly the same thing 5 days ago](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=301196), which is where I found the answer.</sup>