# RFC-3339 Date and Time in Mozilla Thunderbird 102 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS Z)

Tags: thunderbird, date-time, localization

How can I configure Mozilla Thunderbird to format date and time of mails like

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS Z
2023-08-13 19:10:08 +2:00
```

this is one of the [RFC-3339 representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats).

Comment: Does [Customize Date and Time formats in Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird#w_create-date-and-time-format-override-preferences-using-thunderbirds-config-editor) help?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, this worked fine. Do you mind to make an answer from this solution?

Comment: seems there was already a similar question https://superuser.com/questions/144352/change-the-format-of-the-date-column-in-thunderbird

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the format of the date column in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/144352/change-the-format-of-the-date-column-in-thunderbird)

Comment: @Toto yes, this is what I wrote 10h earlier. This is why I suggested to close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I configure Mozilla Thunderbird to format date and time as per RFC-3339?

You can use Thunderbird's Config Editor:

> Thunderbird's date and time format override preferences will allow you
> to apply date and time formats which are different and independent of
> those defined by the regional localizations available in your
> operating system or Thunderbird. You need to create these preferences
> and set them to your preferred format.
>
> This feature is available starting from Thunderbird 91, soon available
> for download from [www.thunderbird.net](http://www.thunderbird.net) (until then, try it in
> Thunderbird 91 beta).
>
> The following string preferences are supported by the platform:
>
> ```
> Preference                                    Example value   Output      Description
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_short    yyyy-MM-dd      2025-12-31  Short date
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_medium                               Medium date
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_long                                 Long date
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_full                                 Full date
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.time_short    HH:mm           09:59       Short time
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.time_medium                               Medium time
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.time_long                                 Long time
> intl.date_time.pattern_override.time_full                                 Full time
> ```

Source: [Customize Date and Time formats in Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird#w_create-date-and-time-format-override-preferences-using-thunderbirds-config-editor)